# UITableViewController hold by a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

My aim is to make a `UITableView` with a certain level of navigation. All I will be using are table views so I really want to go with `UITableViewController` and `UINavigationController`.

I created a subclass of `UITableViewController`, here is the `xib` file:

[image]

It's automatically generated as the class is UITableViewController subclass. Is it enough to get a navigation bar, or should I add something on the xib.

And the relevant code in the `.m` file is the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITableViewController *tableViewController=[[UITableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:tableViewController];
    self.view.window.rootViewController=navController;

    //Create the modal for the UITableView
    array1=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Categorie 1",@"Categorie 2",@"Categorie 3",@"Categorie 4",@"Categorie 5",@"Categorie 6",@"Categorie 7",@"Categorie 8",@"Categorie 9",@"Categorie 10", nil];

}
```

And here is what I got:

[image]

I was waiting to see a navigation bar at the top of the view. I know I am missing something, so please bear with me and give help. Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `MainWindow.xib`, you have to drag a `UINavigationController`, then a `UITableViewController`. Set the class of the `UITableViewController` to your table view controller subclass. Also make sure that the table view controller is set as the root of the navigation controller.